# R: What is the distance function equivalent for this formula?

Tags: r, clustering, distance, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Hi I'm using an R package that calculates distance with this formula here,

```
as.dist(1 - cor(df, use = "pa"))
```

However I cannot seem to find an equivalent dist function from this.  I tried 
"euclidean", "manhattan", or "minkowski".  thanks!

Comment: If you view each object as a direction in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ this is the metric on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ inherited from the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ by inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default cor will compute the Pearson correlation coefficient. Subtracted from $1$ this is know as the [Pearson Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Pearson's_distance).

Comment: thank you this makes sense.  Is there an advantage of running an hierarchical clustering with pearson distance vs something more standard like euclidean?

Comment: You're just measuring correlation so I would assume the clustering algorithm would only be concerned with how data relates, as opposed to where it physically lies.